# Twitter Meta Image Clipping

Tags: twitter, meta

When using the meta tags with twitter, does the image need to match their aspect ratio to prevent clipping, or just be larger than their minimum requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **avatars**, recommended 400x400px.

For **summary cards**, images need to match 240x180 ratio, or else they will be cropped, regardless of if you specify image width and height.

For testing cards:
https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

I hope this saves someone else all of the time that was wasted on this.